# Pulling $_GET data and creating multidimensional array using loop

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a checkout for customers and the data about what's in their cart is being sent to a page (for just now) via $_GET.

I want to extract that data and then populate a multidimensional array with it using a loop.

Here's how I'm naming the data:

```
$itemCount = $_GET['itemCount'];
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $itemCount) {
  ${'item_name_'.$i} = $_GET["item_name_{$i}"];
  ${'item_quantity_'.$i} = $_GET["item_quantity_{$i}"];
  ${'item_price_'.$i} = $_GET["item_price_{$i}"];
  //echo "<br />Name: " .${'item_name_'.$i}. " - Quantity: " .${'item_quantity_'.$i}. " - Price: ".${'item_price_'.$i};
  $i++;
}
```

From here I'd like to create a multidimensional array like such:

```
Array
(
[Item_1] => Array
  (
  [item_name] => Shoe
  [item_quantity] => 2
  [item_price] => 40.00
  )
[Item_2] => Array
  (
  [item_name] => Bag
  [item_quantity] => 1
  [item_price] => 60.00
  )
[Item_3] => Array
  (
  [item_name] => Parrot
  [item_quantity] => 4
  [item_price] => 90.00
  )
  .
  .
  .
)
```

What I'd like to know is if there is a way I can create this array in the existing `while` loop? I'm aware of being able to add data to an array like `$data = []` after delacring an empty array but the actual syntax eludes me.

Maybe I'm completely off the right track and there is a better way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this...

```
   $itemCount = $_GET['itemCount'];
    $i = 1;
    $items = array();

    while ($i <= $itemCount) {
      $items['Item_'.$i]['item_name'] = $_GET["item_name_{$i}"];
      $items['Item_'.$i]['item_quantity'] = $_GET["item_quantity_{$i}"];
      $items['Item_'.$i]['item_price'] = $_GET["item_price_{$i}"];
      $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Terrific,  thank you. It's simple really - set up the array and use the variable variables and square brackets to populate it within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
$itemCount = $_GET['itemCount'];

$i = 1;
while ($i <= $itemCount) {
  $tmp = array();
  $tmp['item_name'] = $_GET["item_name_{$i}"];
  $tmp['item_quantity'] = $_GET["item_quantity_{$i}"];
  $tmp['item_price'] = $_GET["item_price_{$i}"];
  //echo "<br />Name: " .${'item_name_'.$i}. " - Quantity: " .${'item_quantity_'.$i}. " - Price: ".${'item_price_'.$i};
  $i++;
  $result['Item_{$i}'] = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've got what I needed above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$itemCount = $_GET['itemCount'];
$i = 1;
my_array = [];
while ($i <= $itemCount) {
  ${'item_name_'.$i} = $_GET["item_name_{$i}"];
  ${'item_quantity_'.$i} = $_GET["item_quantity_{$i}"];
  ${'item_price_'.$i} = $_GET["item_price_{$i}"];
  //echo "<br />Name: " .${'item_name_'.$i}. " - Quantity: " .${'item_quantity_'.$i}. " - Price: ".${'item_price_'.$i};

my_array["Item_".$i] = array(
   "item_name"=>$_GET["item_name_{$i}"],
   "item_quantity"=>$_GET["item_quantity_{$i}"],
   "item_price"=>$_GET["item_price_{$i}"]
);

  $i++;
}

var_dump(my_array);
```

Comment: Thanks - this works too. I can see the logic in the previous answer so I've ticked them but thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
for($i = 1; isset(${'item_name_'.$i}); $i++){
    $arr['Item_'.$i] = array(
        'item_name' => ${'item_name_'.$i},
        'item_quantity' => ${'item_quantity_'.$i},
        'item_price' => ${'item_price_'.$i},
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I've got what I needed above.